# Lost Space after failed bootcamp partition

Tags: mac, bootcamp, partition

I was trying to resize my bootcamp windows 10 but after failing to figure out a way to do so, I ended up deleting my partition after backing up my files to reinstall windows. After backing up my files I go to make another boot camp partition but I realized that i selected the wrong amount of space so I stupidly force quitted it. Now I'm missing nearly 2 terabytes of space on my hard drive
[image]
[image]
I tried running first aid on them but it doesn't fix the problem. I don't know what to do, somebody please help me fix this problem. If Im missing information to give so you can assist me please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT
[image]
This was the output of diskutil list
And this was the output of diskutil cs list
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from the Terminal application commands `disktuil list` and `diskutil cs list`.

Comment: I added it to the first page. Please help